# how to connect to windows azure vm-hosted team foundation server?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, tfs

I installed TFS on windows azure VM, this VM has public ip:42.134.156.116 for example,i find it is with the port 63630 indeed when i remote this VM with using a downloaded .RDP file.
In visual studio on my local machine, i can not connect to this tfs via its public IP.

I think this maybe a port or firewall issue,but not exactly. because vm has the port 63630 and tfs defualt port is 8080, in addition：the inbound rule of port 8080 has the Profiles "private" and "public", ,
any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Azure go to the VM and click on the endpoints and enable 8080 for your TFS.

Azure also has firewall rules as well as your local VM. The VM as you mentioned looks to have 8080 inbound open.

Regarding your local VM firewall, whether it is public or private depends on what type of network you assigned to your local VM network.

Then try to telnet from your local machine to your VM to confirm the port is open.

Then if that works you should be able to connect. If you can't after that point, it is a TFS or VS  Configuration issue.

If you are having troubles, I normally find it good to disable ALL firewalls, get a good connection, then switch them on one by one until you find out which one is causing the issue.

Comment: thanks very much!:o) you addressed my issue!!! solution in my case is just enable the endpoint 8080 in Azure VM!perfact anwser!!!